# Python Turtle Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: python-2.7, drawing, turtle-graphics

A while ago I made this program to draw a flag and I tried to run it recently and it wasn't working for some reason even though it was when I originally coded it. The stripes draw fine but when it comes to the blue square and stars the turtle pointer doesn't move anywhere. I'm using python 2.7.11 but this was written a year ago I think so could that be the reason why it isn't working? I don't remember what version of python I was using.

```
import turtle

def draw_stripes(length, height, color):
    turtle.speed('fast')
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)

    for i in range(0,6):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.forward(height*2)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_canton(length, height, color):
    turtle.speed('fast')
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(height/13)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(length*(2/5))
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height*(7/13))
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length*(2/5))
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height*(7/13))
    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_star_row_six(length, height, size):
    turtle.speed('fast')
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (6):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*6)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (6):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*6)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (6):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*6)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (6):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*6)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (6):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length * 2)*6)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height*7)

def draw_star_row_five(length, height, size):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(73)

    for i in range (5):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (5):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (5):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.left(253)
    turtle.forward((length*2)*5)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.right(163)

    for i in range (5):
        draw_star(size, 'white')
        turtle.left(73)
        turtle.forward(length*2)
        turtle.right(73)

    turtle.home()

def draw_star(size, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.pendown()

    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(144)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def get_color():
    return r,g,b



def draw_flag(height):
    turtle.speed('fast')
    turtle.setx(-150)
    turtle.color('black')
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(height*1.9)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height*1.9)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(90)
    draw_stripes((height*1.9), height/13, 'red')
    draw_canton((height*1.9), height, 'blue')
    draw_star_row_six(((height*1.9)*(2/5))/12,(height*(7/13))/10, ((height/13)*(4/5))/2)
    draw_star_row_five(((height*1.9)*(2/5))/12,(height*(7/13))/10, ((height/13)*(4/5))/2)

height = float(input('Enter The Height of Your Flag: '))
draw_flag(height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> I'm using python 2.7.11

Because of the different way the division operator works between Python 2 and Python 3, this program will only work properly if run in Python3. Proof:
[image]

In Python2, division truncates: `3 / 2 => 1`
In Python3, division always produces a float: `3 / 2 => 1.5`

Just run your code in Python3 and it should work.

Comment: ...or, better yet, just add `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file

Comment: @Gerrat: That works, but I wouldn't do it unless there was some reason running in Python2 was desirable.

Comment: I wouldn't install a whole new Python version just to avoid adding one line to a program.  He mentioned he was using Python2.7.

Comment: @Gerrat: Guess I forgot that for some people, installing a new version of Python takes more than `apt-get install python3`. If it's a one-off script then yeah, he shouldn't go through more hassle than he needs to.

Comment: @Gerrat I went with your way because I didn't feel like installing 3. Thanks to everyone for helping out.